# Doctrine2 DQL and stored procedure issue

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to execute with doctrine a query like this

```
SELECT convert_currency(p.amount) FROM policy p
```

`convert_currency` is a stored procedure I developed, waiting for a numeric argument.

I follow the DQL steps and create on CoreBundle/DQL the `convertCurrency` function:

```
<?php

namespace DeltaRM\CoreBundle\DQL;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;


class ConvertCurrency extends FunctionNode
{
    public $value = null;


    /**
    * Parse DQL Function
    *
    * @param Parser $parser
    */

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); 
        $this->value = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();        
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
    
    /**
    * Get SQL
    *
    * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
    * @return string
    */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "convert_currency(" . $this->value->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ")";
    }
```

and declare it on my config.yml

And on a repository, I use this function

```
    $qBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("convertCurrency (p.amount)")
        ->from("DeltaRMAssuranceBundle:Police", "p")
         ;
```

It works perfectly, the generated sql statement is

```
SELECT convert_currency(a0_.amount) AS sclr0 FROM police a0_
```

But I get an sql error while doctrine execute it :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function convert_currency(numeric) does not exist
```

If I execute directly on pgadmin the same sql, it works, the function is well known

If I do the exact same thing with max instead of convert_currency, it works perfectly.

What did I miss?

Comment: convert_devise or convert_currency?

Comment: This is full of mismatched errors and typos. Have you edited or "anonymized" any of it? `converCurrency` or `convertCurrency` (missing `t`)? `convert_devise` or `convert_currency`? Etc.

Comment: I wrote my exemple less complicate than the real code, and made some small typo (now corrected) : convert_currency is the stock procedure, convertCurrency is the php function.

My problem is not to wrote and use the DQL function, but to understand why the generated sql send an error when it is executed by doctrine and send the correct result when executed directly on postgre

Thanks